# Simplifying a solution of an equation

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have a linear system, this way:

```
F1 = dpdx + Sin[θ]/Fr^2
F2 = dpdx + Χ*Sin[θ]/(Fr^2) 

solve = Solve[{C2 == 0, Re1*(F1*1/2 + B1 + C1) == 0, 
   Re1*(F1*h^2/2 + B1*h + C1) == Re1/η*(F2*h^2/2 + B2*h + C2), 
   Re1*(F1*h + B1) == Re1/η*(F2*h + B2)}, {B1, B2, C1, C2}]
```

With the solution of this system I calculated another term:

```
In[29]:= Q1 = Integrate[Re1 (F1*y^2/2 + B1*y + C1), {y, h, 1}]
```

I want to separate the solution of this in two terms:

```
(dpdx*Re1)(...) + (Re1/Fr^2)*Sin[θ](...)
```

I tried to use `Collect` but doesn't work.

Comment: Try: `Collect[Integrate[
  Re1 (F1*y^2/2 + (B1 /. solve[[1]])*y + (C1 /. solve[[1]])), {y, h, 
   1}], {(Sin[\[Theta]]*Re1)/Fr^2, Re1*dpdx}]`

Comment: Solves @MariuszIwaniuk. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
F1 = dpdx + Sin[θ]/Fr^2
F2 = dpdx + Χ*Sin[θ]/(Fr^2) 

solve = Solve[{C2 == 0, Re1*(F1*1/2 + B1 + C1) == 0, 
Re1*(F1*h^2/2 + B1*h + C1) == Re1/η*(F2*h^2/2 + B2*h + C2), 
Re1*(F1*h + B1) == Re1/η*(F2*h + B2)}, {B1, B2, C1, C2}]

Collect[Integrate[ Re1 (F1*y^2/2 + (B1 /. solve[[1]])*y + (C1 /. solve[[1]])), 
{y, h, 1}], {(Sin[\[Theta]]*Re1)/Fr^2, Re1*dpdx}]//TeXForm
```

> $$\text{dpdx} \text{Re1} \left(-\frac{h^4}{4 \eta }+\frac{h^4}{4}+\frac{h^3}{2 \eta }-\frac{2 h^3}{3}-\frac{h^2}{4 \eta
>    }+\frac{h^2}{2}-\frac{1}{12}\right)+\frac{\text{Re1} \sin (\theta ) \left(-\frac{h^4 X}{4 \eta }+\frac{h^4}{4}+\frac{h^3 X}{2
>    \eta }-\frac{2 h^3}{3}-\frac{h^2 X}{4 \eta }+\frac{h^2}{2}-\frac{1}{12}\right)}{\text{Fr}^2}$$